# Difference between "ýчите" and "изучáете"?

Tags: перевод

I am curious what the difference is between yчите and изучaете?

Comment: (in addition to the first answer) Another meaning of "учить" (as opposed to "изучать"): to teach.

Comment: So if, i am studying a language it is more appropriate to use the yчит verb?
Is that correct?
How would you formulate that you are studying or learning the russian languge?

Comment: If you use a system, whether under a supervision or on your own, you most likely **study**.  If you are [gradually] acquiring the knowledge, you **learn**.  One can **study** without learning.  One can also **learn** without much effort, without studying.

Comment: @Ana 'учить' is more appropriate.  One would use 'изучать' if one spent many years studying/researching the topic in depth.

Answer (score 5):

учить = learn

изучать = study.